Relative velocity between falling objects
Neglecting air resistance, let's assume body A is 100 meters in diameter and another body B is 1 meter in diameter. If both are released simultaneously from a height of one thousand meters and we photograph their falls independently using a stroboscopic flash at intervals equal to each body's diameter, we'll end up with 10 photos of body A and 1,000 photos of body B. This means that to travel a distance equal to A's diameter, B had to be moving much faster.
Doesn't this contradicts the fact that the objects must hit the ground at the same moment?

Welcome to Physics.SE! Your post is unclear: 1. "body A is 100 meters in diameter and, consequently, body B is 1 meter in diameter" -- "consequently"? Where is the causal relation here? 2. It's not clear how you conclude that $B$ was moving faster. Just because you photographed it more times?

You're taking photos of body B 100 times as often, so you wind up with 100 times as many photos - you take a photo of A every 100m, and a photo of B every 1m. That has nothing to do with the speed of the objects - over 1000m, you'll wind up with 10 photos of A and 1000 photos of B no matter what speed they travel at.

Shades of Zeno's paradox?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes

If you replace meters with mm throughout your question, you will arrive at a much more physically realistic scenario.  It could even be done in a vacuum chamber.


This means that to travel a distance equal to A's diameter, B had to be moving much faster.

This is not correct. The number of photos taken or the frequency of stroboscopic flashes does not affect the acceleration. Acceleration is determined by the force and the mass, not the photos and the stroboscopic flashes.
$$\sum_i \vec F_i = m \vec a$$
